# How to pass Binding of @published variable in function from ObservedObject

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to pass a binding of a `@Published` variable from within my `ObservableObject` to a struct so that its value can be changed inside a closure. I can't quite get it to work. Here is a simplified version of my code below:

```
final class OnboardingStateController: ObservableObject {
  @Published var shouldHide: Bool = false

  func go() {
    MyLogic.fooBar(
      shouldHide: shouldHide // error appears here Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'
    )
  }
}

struct MyLogic {
  static func fooBar(shouldHide: Binding<Bool>) {
    ... SomeClass({ shouldHide.wrappedValue = true })
  }
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative, `Binding` needs a SwiftUI `View` to stay updated because of its [`DynamicProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty) conformance

```
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingStateView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: OnboardingStateController = OnboardingStateController()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("go", action: {
                vm.go()
            })
            Text(vm.shouldHide.description)
        }
    }
}
final class OnboardingStateController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldHide: Bool = false
    
    func go() {
        //This uses a completion handler vs passing the `Binding`
        MyLogic.fooBar(
            shouldHide: { shouldHide in
                self.shouldHide = shouldHide
            }
        )
    }
}

struct MyLogic {
    static func fooBar(shouldHide: (Bool) -> Void) {
        let value = Bool.random() //.. SomeClass({ shouldHide.wrappedValue = true })
        shouldHide(value)
    }
}

struct OnboardingStateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnboardingStateView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear why do you need `Binding` there, but if it is really still needed there, then you can generate it on the fly, like

```
  func go() {
    MyLogic.fooBar(
      shouldHide: Binding(get: { self.shouldHide }, set: { self.shouldHide = $0 })
    )
  }
```

*Note:* it is simplified variant, in which `self` is captured, if you need to avoid it then you take into account using `[weak self]` in each closure.